# yii many_many db criteria filters too specific

Tags: yii, many-to-many

i've got a many_many relation in my Task Model

```
 'keywordlist' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Keyword', 'task_keyword(id_task, id_keyword)'),
```

Well i get my List of all those Tasks with

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = "t.blocked = 0 AND t.answered = 0 AND t.date_deadline > NOW()";
    $criteria->order = 't.id desc';
```

Ok, now a task could have one or * keywords. if i put a filter on my Tasks with

```
$criteria->addCondition('keywordlist.name like \'%html%\'','AND');
```

i receive the wanted task, but only with the html keyword. the task also have more other keywords which wont appear. 
how can i create something like in_array from the keywordlist.name column. and if the keyword is in the result return all the keywords to my task?

if i use for example %p% as the keyword search, it shows up more keywords, if a keyword consists of something with 'p'. but also the other keywords wont show up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly [addInCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) is what you are looking for

```
$criteria->addInCondition('keywordlist.name',array('html','add','other','keywords','here'));
```

Comment: i tried addInCondition before, but same result. problem is, a task could have many keywords and every keyword is stored as a single row in the task_keyword relation. so if i find the searched keyword 'html', it doesnt return me all the other keywords to the task.

Comment: i need a addInCOndition but switched. the keywordlist.name should be the array and the first argument should be the searched keyword

Comment: @GarryCat I don't get what you are asking. If you want all the keywords of the task other than the searched,just add another relation `'allkeywordlist' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Keyword', 'task_keyword(id_task, id_keyword)'),` and use `allkeywordlist` after the search

Comment: $task = new Task();
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "t.blocked = 0 AND t.answered = 0 AND t.date_deadline > NOW()";
        $criteria->order = 't.id desc';
        $criteria->with = 'keywordlist';
        $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->addInCondition('keywordlist.name', array('html'));

$tasks = Task::model()->with('keywordlist')->findAll($criteria);

thats how i get to my tasks and keywords.
i already have ur relation, but its called keywordlist.
you say, after query, a new query only with task ids from the result? isnt that redundant?

Comment: if this helps u: i want a list of the tasks and its keywords if the searched keyword matches only ONE of the task keywords.

task 1 (keywords: html, css, java)
task 2 (keywords: html, javascript, ajax)
task 3 (keywords: java, typo)

the result must be task 1 + 2 and ALL of its keywords if i search for 'html'.

b ut my result NOW is only the keyword 'html' and the others are missin. cause the other keywords doesnt have 'html' in. but one of them matches, so i want all of them.

Comment: i made a little asbtraction with my tables here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/33382-recursion-in-dbcriteria-condition/

Comment: Try `$criteria->together = false` OR  Jst add a reduntant relation `allkeywordlist` as I specified. and use that relation to get the records. Its a workaround. May be some other methods are there. But this will work perfect

Comment: SOLVED: i made a has_many and belongs_to relation out of the many_many and now it works. god knows why...